# Error number: 1052. Column 'id' in field list is ambigious

Tags: sql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to make a pagination table in codeigniter using php and bootstrap. As far as i want to run my code in browser i face the error subscribed in the title. I would be very pleasant and grateful if anyone could help me. Here is my code.

employees_model.php

```
<?php
class employees_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //fetch department details from database
    function get_employees_list($limit, $start)
    {
        $sql = 'select (id, employee_emer, mbiemer, adresa, email), department_emer from employee, department where department.id = employee.id_departament order by employee_emer limit ' . $start . ', ' . $limit;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }
}
?>
```

employees.php

```
<?php
class employees extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        //load the department_model
        $this->load->model('employees_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //pagination settings
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('employees/index');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('employee');
        $config['per_page'] = "5";
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

        //config for bootstrap pagination class integration
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

        //call the model function to get the department data
        $data['emplist'] = $this->employees_model->get_employees_list($config["per_page"], $data['page']);           

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        //load the department_view
        $this->load->view('employees_view',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

employees_view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PHP CodeIgniter Pagination with Bootstrap Styles | Example</title>
    <!--link the bootstrap css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Employee ID</th>
                        <th>Employee Number</th>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Employee Surname</th>
                        <th>Employee Address</th>
                        <th>Employee Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($emplist); ++$i) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo ($page+$i+1); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $emplist[$i]->id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $emplist[$i]->employee_emer; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $emplist[$i]->mbiemer; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $emplist[$i]->adresa; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $emplist[$i]->email; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $emplist[$i]->department_emer; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <?php echo $pagination; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please HELP ME. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Comment: I'd remove those parenthesis from your select query. Also, check your spelling, you appear to have misspelled department in your join. One last thing, start using the correct join syntax, you're using the old and outdated querying style there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to alias Table names. check this

```
         $sql = ' select employee.id, employee_emer, mbiemer, adresa, email, department_emer from employee, department
          where department.id = employee.id_departament order by employee_emer limit ' . $start . ', ' . $limit;
```

Or

```
         $sql = ' select e.id, employee_emer, mbiemer, adresa, email, department_emer 
          from employee e inner join  department d on d.department.id = e.id_departament
          order by employee_emer limit ' . $start . ', ' . $limit;
```

Comment: Error Number: 1241

Operand should contain 1 column(s)

select (employee.id, employee_emer, mbiemer, adresa, email), department_emer from employee, department where department.id = employee.id_departament order by employee_emer limit 0, 5

Comment: I tried the two different versions and i got the same error represented above

Comment: @Lilly take out those parenthesis from the select statement

Comment: Bit of advice, do not concat variables directly into sql. use prepared statements instead. codeigniter provides a decent orm.